# How to catch when application terminates?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, events, exception

I have .NET 4.0 Windows Forms application. I wrote code to catch all events with application ending.

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   try
   {
      SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
      Application.ThreadException += HandleError;
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;
      Application.ApplicationExit += ApplicationExit;
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += CurrentDomain_DomainUnload;
      TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += new EventHandler<UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>(TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException);

      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new frmMain());
      Logger.Info("Normally ending application inner level",MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Logger.Error(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(),ex,true);
   }
   Logger.Info("Normally ending application outter level", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
}
```

But sometimes I got application terminations. Without any messages into internal logs. And without any messages into Windows Events Logs. Question is - how to catch application termination (I want to see something into internal or WinEvents)?